# Changes to rpt file (Crystal report) not getting deployed through vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report, publish

We have crystal reports viewed from a vb.net application. We have made changes to one of the reports. The .rpt file is in resources folder. When we publish the application and install it on user machine the changes done to the report (design related) are not reflected in the file as if no change was made.

Visual Studio - 2010 / 12.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your reportoptions. There is a setting that is called "Save data with report". You have to uncheck this option. Otherwise the report will show the state it was last executed in the reportdesigner.

Maybe this will help?

[image]